# Regex dividing numbers for validation

Tags: ruby, regex

My id is `8808135011086`. The break down is:

- `880813`: birth date in the format yy-mm-dd
- `5011`: gender (anything between `0001`-`4999` is female and `5000`-`9999` is male)
- `0`: whether foreign or not
- `86`: validator number to make sure the rest is legit

Breaking a 13 digit number into groups like this `880813`, `5011`, `0`, `86` was easy to get:

```
/\d{6}\d{4}\d{1}\d{2}/
```

How do I get the regex to look for the `\d{4}` digit and then check if that is between `0001`-`9999` or `5000`-`9999`? I have a code so far looks like this:

```
private
def gender_validation(gender)
  case gender
  when :male
    Employee.id_number.match(/\d{6}\d{4}\d{1}\d{2}/)
    return true
  when :famale
    Employee.id_number.match(/\d{6}\d{4}\d{1}\d{2}/)
    return true
  else
    return false
end
```

If the gender marked was male, then it would find the second part `5223`, and if it was between `5000` and `9999`, it would return true.

I am not just looking for an answer; I would also like to know how to do this.

Comment: -1 for sloppyness. What is `d/{4}`? Where is a bit relevant? Do you mean digit? What does it mean to check `between 0001 and 9999` or `between 5000 and 9999`?

Comment: i do apologise i did ask this question quite late last night and made off in a rush i did change that this morning. as for the params of the question i did explain that in the break down of the ID number

Comment: You only need to check the first digit of the four digit field. female => `[0-4]`, male => `[5-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommended custom validations in [Rails Guides: Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_with)

My suggested solution is:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with EmployeeIdAndGenderValidator

  attr_accessible :id_number, :gender

  .
  .
  .

end

class EmployeeIdAndGenderValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  # my id is 8808135011086 This broken down
  # {880813} is my birdthdate in the format yy-mm-dd
  # {5011} means that i am male anything 
  #     between 5000-9999 is male
  #     and 0001-4999 is female,

  # the next number {0} is weather someone is foreign or not,
  # the next two {86} is a validator number to make sure the rest is legit.

  def validate(record)
    id_number = record.id_number

    unless id_number[/\d{13}/]
      record.errors[:id_number] << "invalid id number"
    else
      brirth_date   = id_number[(0..5)]
      parsed_gender = id_number[(6..9)].to_i
      foreign       = id_number[10]
      validator     = id_number[(-2..-1)]

      validate_gender(parsed_gender, record)
    end
  end

private

  def validate_gender(parsed_gender, record)
    if(parsed_gender < 1 || parsed_gender > 9999)
      record.errors[:id_number] << "the id number had invalid gender number."
    else
      calculate_gender = (parsed_gender <= 4999 ? :female : :male)

      unless record.gender == calculate_gender
        record.errors[:gender] << "The extracted gender dont' match with the selected gender"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Hope it help you!

P/S: sorry for my english.

Comment: that is really good to! thanks for all the effort you put into it

Answer (score 2):

male:

```
/\d{6}\[5-9]\d{3}\d{1}\d{2}/
```

female:

```
/\d{6}\[0-4]\d{3}\d{1}\d{2}/
```